# What determines the shape of tectonic plates?

Tags: plate-tectonics, tectonics, planetary-formation

I understand plate tectonics at approximately the level of the Wikipedia entry, but I have not idea what factors determine the particular locations of the plate boundaries.

Do we have a model for the processes that determine this? Is it completely random (for example, sites impacted later by large meteorites stay molten longer and end up as boundaries, just for a quick hypothesis off the top of my head) or is it determined by some predictable process (pre-established stable subsurface magma currents, perhaps)?

Are all final shapes equally likely? If I was imagining an Earth-like planet whose plate boundaries looked like Homer Simpson is that as plausible as any other specific (if meaningless) jumble of lines?